# Finding Absolute Min/Max with given Domain and Equation. f(x,y)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Question is:

Suppose that $f(x,y) = 5x+3y$ at which $-3 \leq x$, $y \leq 3$.
Find Absolute minimum and maximum of $f(x,y)$.

Since $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y) = 0$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y) = 0$, I am lost how I am supposed to find Absolute minimum and maximum of $f(x,y)$

Is there an alternative way of solving this problem?

Comment: a simple method is $5x$ is linear function, so when $x$ is max $5x$ is max, so does min. $3y$is same case. so combine two cases, $f(x,y)$ will get max when $x,y$ get max. so does min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} f = 5 \neq 0$, and $\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y} f = 3 \neq 0$. So there is no critical point, and the max, min of $f$ occurs at end points of the interval $[-3,3]\times [-3,3]$. Check that $f_{min} = f(-3,-3) = -24$, and $f_{max} = f(3,3) = 24$.